# Related to dansguardian and squid

Tags: networking, squid, dansguardian

Here is the logical topology of my company network:

there is a media converter where we get two static `IP`s that uses the same gateway. This two static `IP`s are the Internet Providers for other two networks from my company. On the server from the first network I have installed `DansGuardian` with `squid`. These days, some co-workers (that are in the second network managed by a router) claimed that they experience hard access on the web.

**My question**: is it possible for `DansGuardian` or `squid` to affect the other network? If yes, how should I prevent this?

Bellow is an image with my network architecture:

[image]

Comment: Seems unlikely, but it is hard to answer the question without more detail. A network diagram would be great.

Comment: @TomNewton I made a trial.

Comment: is dansguardian/squid in transparent mode?

Comment: @TomNewton yes.

Comment: are clients 1.x and 2.x on separate subnets?

Comment: @TomNewton No. Here is the idea: server 1 external IP: A.A.A.66, router 2 external IP: A.A.A.55, both with the same netmask and gateway. LAN server 1: b.b.b.0, LAN network 2: c.c.c.0

Comment: @TomNewton See the update on image. Hope to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

OK - time for a proper answer.
I think it is really unlikely, if the network diagram is representative, that dansguardian is getting in the way of users on LAN2 browsing.

It is worth checking: 
1. That there are no entries in the squid log on server1 with ip c.c.c.0/16
2. That routing on router 2 is going straight to the media converter and not being filtered by the other router.

At this point you might want to actually see the users' problems first hand on LAN2, so you can see what their "symptoms" are.